# retrieving the arraylist from inside map

Tags: java

I have an query , I have an array list that conatain different arraylist inside as shown below

```
List<abcInfo> abcabcdata = new ArrayList<abcInfo>(); //first arraylist

abcInfo abcdeed = new abcInfo();
        abcdeed.setHeader("AAAA");
        abcdeed.setabcdata(getNormalFuturesFeedList()); //List<FuturesFeedObject> it contains another arraylist
        abcabcdata.add(abcdeed);

        abcInfo abcdgen= new abcInfo();
        abcdgen.setHeader("BBBB");
        abcdgen.setabcdata(getabcdgenList()); //this method reurn arraylist, it contains list inside another arraylist
        abcabcdata.add(abcdgen);
```

Now the query is I am putting the final list in a map, so reportmap is itself an arraylist that contain two different arraylist inside it

```
HashMap<String, Object> abcdata = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        abcdata.put("YTRE", abcabcdata);
```

And finally I am retieving this array list on the basis of key

```
List<abcInfo> listWDownNoticesInfo = (ArrayList<abcInfo>)abcdata.get("YTRE");
```

Now my query is that I have to make a count of those whose header was AAAA and count of those whose header was Payment in BBBB please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `List` , check each element and count . And please follow [Java coding and naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

```
List<abcInfo> listWDownNoticesInfo = (ArrayList<abcInfo>)abcdata.get("YTRE");
Iterator<abcInfo> itr = listWDownNoticesInfo .iterator();
int countA = 0;
int countB = 0;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    abcInfo element = itr.next();
    if(element.getHeader().equals("AAAA")){
      countA++;
    }
    if(element.getHeader().equals("BBBB")){
      countB++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry , but its **The New Idiot** .

Answer (score 0):

```
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
for(abcInfo obj:listWDownNoticesInfo){

 if(obj.getHeader.equals("AAA")
   count1++;
 else  if(obj.getHeader.equals("BBB")
   count2++;

}

System.out.println("Header AAA count:"+count1);
System.out.println("Header BBB count:"+cpunt2);
```